# numpy loadtxt for 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning, computer-vision

I was loading iris dataset using loadtxt function of numpy and expected the shape of the ndarray so returned to be (150,5), but the shape so returned comes out to be (150,).So apparently the loadtxt method is storing the 2D array as list of rows. How can I make the loadtxt method return the data as 2D array.Please don't suggest pandas here.

Well, this is the simple code snippet that I used:

```
import numpy as np


values = np.genfromtxt('iris.txt', delimiter=',',dtype={'names': ('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'label'),
                      'formats': (np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, 'U15')}, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
print(values.shape)
```

Comment: You are getting `shape (150,)` of composite `dtype`. Since `"label"` is not homogeneous (same `dtype` as others), you **cannot** make it `(150, 5)` unless you want to store `object`, which is inefficient.

Comment: You could load 4 columns as a 2d array of floats, but the `label` string column has to be loaded separately.

Comment: Look at `values.dtypes`, and then read up on structured arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `loadtxt` docs for `dtype`:

```
Data-type of the resulting array; default: float.  If this is a
structured data-type, the resulting array will be 1-dimensional, and
each row will be interpreted as an element of the array.  In this
case, the number of columns used must match the number of fields in
the data-type.
```

Your `dtype` is a structured data-type:

```
dtype={'names': ('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'label'),
       'formats': (np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, 'U15')}
```

5 fields matching the 5 values in `usecols`.

You access fields with name indexing, e.g. `values['sepal length']`, `values['label']`.